# How to identify the original manufacturer of lenses branded Vivitar?

Tags: lens, old-lenses, vintage

There are Vivitar-branded lenses for which I wish to identify the manufacturer. I have read that Vivitar encoded the manufacturer in the serial number, so in principle, I just need to find a list of applicable manufacturer codes.

What are the manufacturer codes for lenses that have been rebranded Vivitar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During the 1970s and early 1990s, **Vivitar** serial numbers took the following form:

> **MM Y WW SSS**
>
> MM = manufacturer code
>     Y = year; may be ambiguous, for instance 1979 and 1989
>     WW = week
>     SSS = item-specific serial number

The manufacturer codes used by Vivitar are:

> *06 - Olympus*
> 09 - Cosina Company, Ltd.
> 13 - Schneider Kreuznach
> 22 - Kino Precision
> 25 - Ozone Optical Co., Ltd.
> 28 - Komine Co., Ltd.
> 32 - Makina Optical Co., Ltd
> 33 - Asanuma & Co., Ltd
> 37 - Tokina Optical Company, Ltd
> 42 - Bauer (possibly Bauer trademark holder Robert Bosch GmbH)
> 44 - Perkin-Elmer
> 47 - Chinon Industries, Inc.
> 51 - Tokyo Trading (possibly a corruption of Tokyo Koki, a Tokina predecessor)
> 56 - Kyoei Shoji Company, Ltd.
> 61 - Samyang Optics Co., Ltd
> 75 - Hoya Corporation
> 77 - Kobori Mfg Co. Ltd
> 81 - Polar

Of these, a few appear to be highly regarded, such as Kino/Kiron (22) and Komine (28). Others have become household names, such as Tokina (37) and Samyang (61).

See also:

- [Camera Wiki: Vivitar serial numbers](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Vivitar_serial_numbers)
- [Who made that Vivitar Lens?](https://cameraquest.com/VivLensManuf.htm)

Comment: Any idea where vivitar lenses sat in the manufacturing line? As in, were a group of lenses pulled at random for branding or did vivitar get the bottom of the barrel so to speak?

Comment: Vivitar designed some of their own lenses, so at least those would have had entire manufacturing lines devoted to them. They also had a premium line of lenses called "Series 1", which were likely entrusted only to manufacturers with proven track records. Aside from that, I don't know how manufacturers managed their production lines.